# texture not showing on new rearranged UV maps

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

i used a mesh from character creator 3. I noticed the UV maps on his single body mesh consisted of multiple UVs  (head, body, arm, leg)

My main intention was to combine all the meshes into 1 uv map by rearranging them (refer picture)
.Somehow i realized that even though i rearranged the uvs, but the projection still follows the old uv separated body parts, resulting the texture don't show up on the 3d panel. Do i need to do retarget function , so the UV will follow the new repositioned uv meshes? Thank you

[image: UV map]

Comment: in the Object Data panel do you have several UV Maps and have you chosen the right one in the list?

Comment: Ahh thank you so much on pointing on the right direction! Yes i still used old uvmaps :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Object Data panel > UV Maps*, make sure that you're using the good UV map:

[image]